# Detect if app React app is running in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, prop, react-native-ios

Passing initial properties for React Native doesn't work when following an example.

The the problem is that the value of `isSimulator` gets evaluated as `undefined`.

Xcode:

```
  BOOL isSimulator = NO;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  isSimulator = YES;
#endif

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"ReactProject"
                                               initialProperties:@{@"isSimulator": @(isSimulator)}
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

React:

```
var isSimulator = this.props.isSimulator;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

And detect if simulator by using DeviceInfo.getModel() it'll return simulator if it's simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: [Github Link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#isemulator)

`const isEmulator = DeviceInfo.isEmulator(); // false`

It works for me with `Xcode`